# How to notify an object from another object in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application. In addition to REST APIs my application also has a TCP server. TCP Server is created using configuration file as described in [Spring Boot TCP and UDP Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html)

Inside the TCP server, I create object instances dynamically based on the data in a table. Insertion of a new row into this table is done via REST API.

Initially, when the TCP server starts, it loads the rows from a table and creates objects.

Any suggestions on how to inform TCP server when somebody adds a new row through REST POST command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used mediator patten given here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) to resolve the issue.